# Restoring files from a Windows 7 backup to a Ubuntu PC

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore

I am building a PC running Ubuntu 18.04LTS to replace a Windows 7 machine (about flipping time I hear you say!) for someone I help with their tech.

The backup utility from Win7 has been used to make a system backup with the data written to an external USB drive.

I will be manually copying files from Documents, Pictures, Music to the new setup initially.

I want to guard against finding in the future that there are files/folders that suddenly become needed.

I'd like to know if there is a utility for Ubuntu that can work with the .zip files and catalogs that the Win7 backup utility creates that would allow for files/folders to be restored without me having to find a Windows machine to use to get the files from the USB drive.

edit:
It is about finding a manageable way to see and extract the files contained in the set of files are are titled 'Backup Files xxx.zip'
Thanks

Comment: It is about finding a manageable way to see and extract the files contained in the set of files are are titled 'Backup Files xxx.zip'

Comment: It depends... normally I would assume a backup utility will encrypt the files so it can claim the backup is not altered. If so ... no you will not be able to do that. If you need that you would have to zip the files yourself and store them on an external medium

Comment: @Rinzwind IIRC, Windows 7's "ZIP" backups aren't encrypted in any way. The problem just becomes figuring out which files live in which ZIP files.

Comment: In linux you get use 'zgrep' on zipped files

Comment: @Your'reAGit ... you have hit the nail on the head